# How to get tkinter canvas object to move around a circle

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a canvas created image:

[image]

On my canvas, I have drawn a circle:

[image]

The code to produce this circle:

```
def create_circle(x, y, r, canvasName): #center coordinates, radius
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvasName.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, outline='red')
create_circle(100, 100, 50, canvas)
```

I would like to get the canvas created image to follow the canvas drawn circle exactly (go round the circle), by each pixel. How is this possible?

To elaborate, here is a demonstration of what I want the canvas image to do:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/8218fe1c82008f2ed034a78b46f787e6.mp4]

Comment: You would periodically call `CANVAS.coords(IMAGE, CX+R*math.sin(A), CY+R*math.cos(A))`, where CX, CY, R are the center and radius of your circle, and A is an angle (in radians) that you increase slightly each time (or decrease, to make it go the other direction).  Note that your circle object plays no part in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `root.after` to send a periodic call to change the coordinates of your image. After that its just a matter of calculating the new x, y positions of your image in each call.

```
import tkinter as tk
from math import cos, sin, radians

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

image = tk.PhotoImage(file="plane.png").subsample(4,4)

def create_circle(x, y, r, canvasName):
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvasName.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, outline='red')

def move(angle):
    if angle >=360:
        angle = 0
    x = 200 * cos(radians(angle))
    y = 200 * sin(radians(angle))
    angle+=1
    canvas.coords(plane, 250+x, 250+y)
    root.after(10, move, angle)

create_circle(250, 250, 200, canvas)
plane = canvas.create_image(450,250,image=image)

root.after(10, move, 0)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why you are adding 250 to x and y?

Comment: It's the x y position of the center of the circle. In your original it will be adding 100 to x and y.

Comment: So if I change the size of the circle x and y position, would I need to change anything else?

Comment: You need to change the radius, and x y loc (which is 100 and 100 in your original snippet).